# How to assign xml string in div's innerhtml along with Xslt Text

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have write my own style sheet for XML, When I use this xslt with as a reference of xml style sheet then it is working fine, but when i am assigning it to div's innerhtml then it is not working.

Comment: Can you post some code for a detailed and robust answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using div you can use asp .net XML control, u can specify your xslt file name and document  data from code behind or by .aspx page.

```
 <asp:Xml ID="xmlViewControl" runat="server" TransformSource="Default.xsl">
                </asp:Xml>
```

try it ,it will be work.